# Are blocks submitted to a dispatch group executed serially or concurrently?

Tags: grand-central-dispatch

Dispatch groups are a GCD feature the allows one to submit blocks to be dispatched to certain queues. Regarding the queues, the blocks are dispatched acording to the queue's type: if a queue is serial, the block is going to be executed serially in relation to that queue; if a queue is concurrent, the same happens, but concurrently.

However, regarding the group, dispatches occur serially or concurrently in relation to each other? I mean, if a group has a queue of dispatch queues and blocks to be dispatched, is the next dispatch executed only when the previous one gets finished?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Membership in a dispatch group is independent of execution order.

A dispatch group is really just a counter, `dispatch_group_enter(group)` increments the counter and  `dispatch_group_leave(group)` decrements the counter.

`dispatch_group_async(group, queue, block)` is a shortcut for:

```
dispatch_group_enter(group);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    block();
    dispatch_group_leave(group);
});
```

i.e. the execution order of blocks submitted via `dispatch_group_async(group, queue, block)` depends only on the `queue`(s) specified.

When the dispatch group counter reaches zero (the group becomes empty), all waiters in `dispatch_group_wait(group)` are woken up, and any blocks that have been submitted to the group via `dispatch_group_notify(group, queue, block)` are all async'd to their respective `queue`s (i.e. these blocks may execute concurrently if the specified `queue`s are concurrent/independent).